# Have an iPad's viewable area visible on your computer monitor for remote web-meeting training?

Tags: ipad

I want to demo the usage of my iPad on my computer screen so that I can transmit it to other people during a training session using a web conference tool (like dimdim.com, gotomeeting.com, fuzemeeting.com, etc...)  Is there a way to stream an iPad's display to a computer so it would be visible in such a screen casting software?

My current ad-hoc solution for this would be to use a webcam to livecast me using a physical (real life) iPad and broadcast that to other users for training.  This is undesirable due to the difficulty in really seeing the iPad well.

So I'm hoping someone has a way to:
1) Video output the iPad's display to my computer screen.
2) Emulate an iPad with a installed app (not having the source code) on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the [iPad/iPhone development tools](http://developer.apple.com/ipad/sdk/).  It includes an iPhone simulator (and, I hope, an iPad simulator), which you can run on a Mac.  It will not be nearly as fluid as using it by itself, mind you, and I doubt you'll be able to install third-party apps.  [I haven't actually tried it myself.]

You will need to sign up for a free Apple Developer Connection membership.  (If I understand correctly, the $99 developer fee is only needed if you are going to try to get apps into the app store.  For playing around and testing code on the computer, you don't need it).

Comment: I want to let sales people demo my iPad application to prospects/customers.  I don't want to give the sales people the source code and some don't have Mac computers.

Comment: How do other people demo their apps?  I imagine there are videos on the internet, and perhaps just using a video camera shooting at your device is your best bet.  Will the sales people have iPads?  Can they run a lite version of your software?

Comment: Cool idea to get this done without the actual hardware required.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you really want is a VNC server that runs on the iPad.  There is an application called Veency, but according to [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/d/mobilize/21-apps-apple-doesnt-want-your-iphone-969&current=15&last=1), though, it is an application you will not find in the app store.  I don't know of anything that you can use without jailbreaking your device :(

Comment: Yep, this is what most people use. It's easy enough to jailbreak at the moment using the Spirit jailbreak.

Comment: Does Veency work on the iPad?

Comment: Yep. According to http://spreadsheets.google.com/lv?key=tHnYEq4SmhIGOgbH9TVgXgA&f=true&gid=0 .

Answer (score 3):

Veency would be the easiest way to do this (It has recently been modified to also be compatible with the iPad as well as the original iPhone and iPod Touch platforms it was intended for). Jailbreak your iPad using Spirit @ spiritjb.com, then search for the Veency package in Cydia on your iPad, then use a VNC client on your computer to view the iPad's screen via WiFi. If necessary, you can find out your iPad's IP address under Wifi in the Settings 'app.' Depending on your used VNC client, you should also be able to use mouse and keyboard input from your computer on your iPad. Some good VNC clients are RealVNC for Windows, or Chicken of the VNC for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, I'd say, use [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/).

I work for a school division and our teachers are very happy about being able to show iOS devices on their computers (and thus, through their projectors).  The software isn't free, but isn't terribly expensive.

I imagine there are [other applications now that meet this need](http://alternativeto.net/software/airserver/) as well, but I can't vouch for them.